# IEnumerable is readonly.. but it isn't?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Many topics on this question. Wondering why sometimes the collection is readonly, and sometimes not. I came across an issue in a .NET Core 3.1 project where the intention was to modify a collection within a `foreach` loop. The issue was after the iteration, however the collection was not modified at all... which based on my understanding makes sense.

```
public async Task DoFoo(IEnumerable<SomeClass> data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            item.Id = item.SomeOtherValue;
            //note: checked and Id is {get;set;}
        }

        await SaveData(data, cancellationToken);
}
```

The result was that id was still null. casting to list and then modifying fixed the issue.

Testing however on .net fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/bQvf40) shows that the collection does in fact get altered. Which is really not what I expected. Can anyone explain why this is getting changed.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var iePerson = new[] { new Person(){Id = 2, Name="SomeName", Other=5} }; //note other = 5
        IEnumerable<Person> pien = iePerson; //writing this way to ensure we are creating IEnumable
        DoFoo(pien); 
    }
    
    private static void DoFoo(IEnumerable<Person> entities)
    {
        foreach(Person p in entities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Id);
            p.Id = p.Other;
        }
                
        foreach(Person p in entities)
            Console.WriteLine(p.Id);
                
        //result is 
        //2
        //5 <--- was expecting to see 2... 

    }
    
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public int Other {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: p.Id = p.Other this line makes it 5. Objects are mutable type. Mutable type, in C#, is a type of object whose data members, such as properties, data and fields, can be modified after its creation.

Comment: Except in my work code.. Id as well is just basic 
public string Id { get; set; }

Except SomeClass.Id was not getting altered at all.

Comment: seems like you're querying the items multiple times without saving the changes. So depending on what that `entities`-collection is, you should materialize it into a list or an array. So where does the collection come from? And what runtime-type is it?

Comment: are you sure  item.SomeOtherValue is not null ?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, as stated, I needed to change the method to cast it to list in order to modify the entities, which like i said, makes sense as I thought IEnumerable is readonly. When testing out the theory however on .netFiddle, I cannot reproduce the expectation that the collection was never altered.  
User19139505 Yes. SomeOtherValue was never null. I was observing in the breakpoint, that item.id got assigned, but data was never updated.

Comment: we don't know where your actual collection comes from. All we know is that within your fiddle you create an array, so the data already *is* in memory. I suppose your actual collection comes from a database or something. So when you iterate the collection, you perform a query on that database. Afterwards you modify the data, but don't write it back to the database. Finally you query the data again which will show the original data of course.

Comment: Are you sure `IEnumerable<Person>` represents an in-memory collection? Could it perhaps represent a stream of results from a database query (such as with Entity Framework)? Or do you perhaps have a `.Select(x => new Person()` in the chain before you pass it to `DoFoo`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yes. I think this is likely the issue. The IEnumerable<SomeClass> is in fact from a cosmos /Entity Framework query, which I guess makes sense as it would be not updateable until it gets casted to memory. This makes total sense. And my example is not valid because it is already inMemory. Thanks all for taking the time to throw darts at the wall. WRT the question about selecting to a new obj etc.. nope.. the entire method was posted.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a misunderstanding on what a `List` is and what an `Enumerable` is. The former is a **materialized** in-memory data-structure, that means a collection of items that exist in memory. You can access the items in that collection by index, add new items or remove items.

The latter is just a generalization which states only that you can **iterate that collection**. However it makes no guarantees about where that data comes from. It might be an in-memory collection such as a list, however it might also be a database or some stream. Which is crucial in your case. **Every time you ask your `IEnumerable` to give you the data, it performs a query on the underlying data-store** - whatever that might be. In your fiddle that underlying data-storage is an array - something that has already been materialized into memory. In your app however chances are it's some stream or a database. So when you iterate the enumerable, **you execute the query again**. This also omits every modification you did in between, because you never transmitted those changes back to the data-storage.

Calling `ToList` on your collection (which by the way is not the same as casting) will help to see the changes within your app, as you materialize the data into memory and modify it there. However it won't help you in saving those changes back into the database.

Casting on the other hand won't change the underlying data-storage. So if it's already an array, down-casting it to an `IEnumerable` won't change anything. Of course iterating that enumerable twice will also perform the query twice - but as that storage is an array, that won't hurt. On a database however, it *will* hurt much.

To keep long stories short: in your real-world scenarios you have a database. Changing any of its elements in your client-app won't be automatically reflected in the database regardless if it's a list, an array or just an `IEnumerable`. You can see the changes in your client, but as soon as you query the items again (which is done in case of `IEnumerable`, see above), the changes are lost. Only when you **explicitely save** it the changes are synced back to your database.

In your fiddle on the other hand you don't have a database, but a **materialized** (=in-memory)-collection, so there's no need to sync anything back at all. You can modify every element in your collection (again regardless if it's an array, a list or just an `IEnumerable`) and see the changes in your client.

Comment: Yes. The issue was indeed that the collection was not in memory at the point of looping as it was an EF query stream. This was stated in the OP.  I got confused as I was trying to emulate the issue in fiddle and wondering why I was having no issues there.